# trimming a string in php

Tags: php, string, if-statement, trim, equality

i'm still quite new to programming, so please excuse me.

I need to do the following:

Right now i have a string being output with two value: one with characters and numbers, a comma and the second with just a boolean value.

```
9fjrie93, 1
```

I would like to trim the string so it just ourputs as the boolean value. e.g.

```
1
```

I then need to perform an equality check on the boolean value. If it's 1 do one thing, else do something else. Would a simple if statement suffuce?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for explode if it's always the last character.

```
<?php
$val = '9fjrie93, 1';
if( substr( $val, -1 ) === '1' ) {
    // do stuff.
}
else {
    // do stuff. Just other stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
$vals = explode(", ", "9fjrie93, 1");
if ($vals[1]) ...
```

Comment: `arrays` use more storage space as compare to `strings`.

Comment: True, explode is an option, especially if you would want to use first value as well.

Comment: well, the OP doesn't mention that in the question, so its an assumption, hence it better to use `strings`

Comment: As I said explode is an option

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `list` to name the results returned:

```
$original_str = '9fjrie93, 1';
list($characters, $boolean) = explode(', ', $original_str);
echo $boolean;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $output = str_replace(',', '', strstr('9fjrie93, 1', ','));
 if( $output == '1' ) {
   ....do something
  } else {
  ...do something else
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $str = '9fjrie93, 1';
    $str = explode(', ', $str); //it returns array('9fjrie93', '1')
    $str = end($str); //takes the last element of the array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mystring = '9fjrie93, 1';
$findme   = ',';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
$i= substr($mystring,$pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "9fjrie93, 1";
$val = substr($string, (strrpos($string, ',')+1));
```

Don't use explode since it's slower

Comment: `substr($string, -1)` would suffice.

Comment: which is not a representation of a boolean, so that wouldn't make sense anyway ;)

Comment: true, sorry I missed that in the question. If you are always sure there is only a 1 or a 0 at the end then just check the last char

Answer (score 0):

If the 1 is always at the end of the line, you can do:

```
$line = '9fjrie93, 1'
if ( $line[strlen([$line])-1] == '1' ) {
    // do stuff
} else {
    // do other stuff
}
```

Which should at least perform better than `explode`, `str_replace` and `substr` solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pos = strpos($source_str, ',');
substr($source_str, $x_pos + 1);
```

hope this will solve it.