# Select only one character from a string

Tags: php, string, trim

I have a string variable which looks something like this: `fasdhkfsdk, 1 sdfs`

The amount of front and back characters in the string will differe in size, but the comma and the binary value will always be there (the value will change from 1 to 0).

I need a way to chop everything left and right of the binary value off and leave only the 1 or 0. The amount of characters on both sides do change, so I don't think that I can use substr or explode, but I could be wrong

Thanks very much

p.s. Yes, there will always be a comma and a space before the binary digit

Comment: is there always a comma before the binary?

Comment: will that be the only comma in the string?

Comment: will that be the only numerical character, will there always be spaces around it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [trimming a string in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531456/trimming-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use regex like this:

```
$string = "fasdhkfsdk, 1 sdfs";
echo preg_replace("[^01]", "", $string);
```

that will remove everything but 0's and 1's, if you're sure the string will only be characters from the alphabet

Answer (score 6):

Example 1 `sscanf`

```
$string = "fasdhkfsdk, 1 sdfs" ;
$part = sscanf($string, "%s %d %s");
echo $part[1];
```

Another Example with `sscanf`

```
$string = "fasdhkfsdk, 1 sdfs" ;
$part = sscanf($string, "%s %d %s",$prifix,$number,$sufix);
print($number);
```

Example 2 `preg_match_all`

```
$string = "fasdhkfsdk, 1 sdfs" ;
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $string, $matches);
print($matches[0][0]);
```

Example 3 `filter_var`

```
$string = "fasdhkfsdk, 1 sdfs" ;
$int = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
print($int);
```

Example 4 `substr` with `strrpos`

```
//credit: slugonamission

$string = "fasdhkfsdk, 1 sdfs" ;
echo trim(substr($string , strrpos($string,",") + 1 ,2));
```

Output

```
 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) a try.

Comment: Regex is completely overkill for this. You know the comma will be there, so run `strrpos` on the comma and use `substring`.

Comment: @slugonamission but we don't know if that will be the only comma!

Comment: I generally assume in cases like this that it will :P.

Comment: @slugonamission nice option .. just added it to part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Explode the string first, like
`$r = explode(",",$string)`

Then just access the second part of the array $r and get the second char.

```
echo $r[1][1];
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You just want the binary value right? You want to know if it's a 1 or a 0.
Try

```
$ar = explode(",", "fasdhkfsdk, 1 sdfs"); // split on the comma
echo(intval($ar[1])); // convert everything after the comma to an int.  should be 0 or 1
```